# rlwrap: Could not open master pty: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, pty, rlwrap

When trying to run `rlwrap tclsh` I am getting this error message:

```
rlwrap: Could not open master pty: No such file or directory
```

What causes this? How to fix this issue?

P.S. I am running 64 bit CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

check */dev/ptmx*
it should have 
*crw-rw-rw-*
I once had it 
*crw-------*
this caused the error message at my system.

see also *man ptmx*:

> The  file  /dev/ptmx is a character file with major number 5 and minor number 2, usually of mode 0666 and owner.group of root.root.  It is used to create a pseudo-terminal master and slave pair.