# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows - rlwrap could not open master pty

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, rlwrap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, I'm receiving an error from any `rlwrap` command.

```
root@localhost:~# rlwrap ls
rlwrap: Could not open master pty: No such file or directory
```

I've made sure that /dev/ptmx has the correct permissions

```
root@localhost:~# ls -ld /dev/ptmx
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 2 Apr  9 22:44 /dev/ptmx
```

Yet I still can't get it working. Am I the only one encountering this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) doesn't (yet?) have a working `pty` implementation. I suspect that opening `/dev/ptmx` always fails for this reason, even though the device file exists and has the right permissions.

`rlwrap`, but also programs like `screen` and `tmux`, are never going to work without a `pty` device. They fail under WSL for the same reason as `rlwrap`.

Hans (`rlwrap` maintainer)

Comment: September 2018 - Rlwrap seems to be working on WSL now

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on my Ubuntu 16.04. Purging and re-installing rlwrap solved the problem for me.

```
sudo apt-get purge rlwrap
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```

Of course this is a bit of a different issue because it's not exactly WSL.

Comment: As you say, your problem was with Ubuntu on Linux, not with Windows: a completely different issue. Most probably caused by [incorrect permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886629/rlwrap-could-not-open-master-pty-no-such-file-or-directory) on /dev/ptmx

Comment: Sry, I forgot to mention that I was aware of that post and that the permissions were set correctly when I ran into the problem. That WSL is not exactly the same as native Ubuntu is, of course, correct.

Comment: No need to say sorry! But whoever has this problem on _linux_ (with correct permissions for `/dev/ptmx`),  please [file a bug report](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues)