# xterm fails under WSL: not enough ptys

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Having just updated to the newest Windows 10 release (build 14316), I started the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which is supposed to run an Ubuntu installation on Windows.

When I type `xterm` in terminal I get error:

```
xterm: Error 32, errno 2: No such file or directory
Reason: get_pty: not enough ptys
```

What's the problem?
I would like to install KDE konsole, it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) doesn't (yet) have a working pseudo-terminal (`pty`) implementation. Programs that need to create one (like `xterm`, but also `konsole`, `screen` and `rlwrap`) will invariably fail with `ENOENT` ("No such file or directory")

see also: [rlwrap could not open master pty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523748/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-rlwrap-could-not-open-master-pty/36529661#36529661)

EDIT: as of june 9 2016, and build 14361,  this problem appears to have been solved (see the comments on [Microsofts github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/323) and Alexis' comment below)

Comment: There is a way to implement `pty`?

Comment: @lukassz: WSL is closed source, so only Microsoft can do that - and they probably will.

Comment: According to a comment on [Microsoft's github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/323) "this one is near the top of our priority list."